# two serial tasks slower than parallel

Tags: java

Hi I have a webapp - and in one method I need to encrypt part of data from request and store them on disk and return response.

Response is in no way related to encryption.

The encryption is quite time demanding however. How to make threads or so properly in this problem?

I tried something like

Thread thread ...

thread.start();

or

JobDetail job = encryptionScheduler.getJobDetail(jobDetail.getName(), jobDetail.getGroup());

encryptionScheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail,TriggerUtils.makeImmediateTrigger("encryptionTrigger",1,1)

I tried servlet where before encryption I close the outpuStream.

or: Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

But whatever I tried a client has to wait longer.

btw: why is that so? Can it be faster?

I haven't tried to start thread after context initalization and wait somehow for method needing encryption.

how to speed up this?

thank you

--------------EDIT:
//I use axis 1.4, where I have Handler, which in invoke method encrypt a value:

```
try {
    LogFile logFile = new LogFile(strategy,nodeValue,path, new Date());
    LogQueue.queue.add(logFile);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
    }

EExecutor.executorService.execute(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                LogFile poll = LogQueue.queue.poll();
                String strategy = poll.getStrategy();
                    String value = poll.getNodeValue();
                    value = encrypt(strategy,value);
                    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(poll.getPath(), true )),"UTF-8"));
                    writer.print(value);
                    writer.close();
                }catch (IOException e  ) {
                    log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
                } 
            }

        });
        } catch (Throwable e ) {
            log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
        }
```

//besides I have executor service

```
public class EExecutor { public static ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();}
```

//and what's really interesting.. when I move encryption from this handler away into another handler which is called
last when I send response! It's faster. But when I leave it in one of the first handlers when I receive request. It's even slower without using threads/servlet etc.

Comment: I don't think speed depends of the Thread utilization but implementation... we may need more code in order to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper way to do something like this is to have a [message queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue), such as the standard J2EE [JMS](http://java.sun.com/products/jms/).

In a message queue, you have one software component whose job it is to receive messages (such as requests to encrypt some resource, as in your case), and make the request "durable" in a transactional way. Then some independent process polls the message queue for new messages, takes action on them, and transactionally marks the messages as received.

Answer (score 5):

Threads only help you if parts of your task can be done in parallel. It sounds like you're waiting for the encryption to finish before returning the result. If it's necessary for you to do that (e.g., because the encrypted data *is* the result) then doing the encryption on a separate thread won't help you here---all it will do is introduce the overhead of creating and switching to a different thread.

**Edit:** If you're starting a *new* thread for each encryption you do, then that might be part of your problem. Creating new threads is relatively expensive. A better way is to use an `ExecutorService` with an unbounded queue. If you don't care about the order in which the encryption step happens (i.e., if it's ok that the encryption which started due to a request at time t finishes later than one which started at time t', and t < t'), then you can let the `ExecutorService` have more than a single thread. That will give you both greater concurrency and save you the overhead of recreating threads all the time, since an `ExecutorService` pools and reuses threads.

Comment: That is a very important point often missed. If you had *two* things to encrypt, running those in parallel would/might help, or if the encryption routine was itself in parallel, that would benefit as well, but spawning a thread to perform one action which the parent would wait for.... still has a time cost of the whole operation as well as the spawning of the thread.

Comment: I'm sorry for misleading headline. one important thing is I don't need to wait for results. It can run parallel or even encryption can happen later

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. When I created one ExecutorService and every time I need to encrypt, I execute Runnable It's still slower :) The task takes around 2-3seconds.

Comment: I think we need to see your code to get a better idea of what's happening.

Comment: I guess why is that so, I've made it faster finally. just by moving code somewhere else. I'll explain in edited version.